# Templates - menu

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

How can I use the same menu list below (ie, a template base) for different apps (eg, app1, app2, etc.)
I guess what I'm asking is when I'm in app1, I like to see this:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="/app1/" class="home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="/app1/help" class="help">Help</a></li>
</ul>
```

when in app2:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="/app2/" class="home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="/app2/help" class="help">Help</a></li>
</ul>
```

Many thanks in advance.

PS: I tried `{{ request.path }}` and `{{ request.get_full_path }}` to no avail.

Comment: I don't understand what TEMPLATE_DIRS has to do with anything - that has no relationship with URLs or links.

Comment: You are right, and I deleted it, but I still don't know to achieve this.

Comment: When you write 'app' you mean applications of your project? or different site instance?

Comment: I mean application my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
<!-- project/templates/base.html -->
<html>
  ...
  <ul>
      {% include 'fragments/own_menu.html' %}
  </ul>
  ...
</html>
```

and put a template named `fragments/own_menu.html` inside the templates folder of each app. e.g.

```
app1
   templates/
     fragments/
         own_menu.html
```

which code should looks like:

```
<li><a href="/app1/" class="home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/app1/help" class="help">Help</a></li>
```

your app2:

```
app2
   templates/
      fragments/
         own_menu.html
```

which code should looks like:

```
<li><a href="/app2/" class="home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/app2/help" class="help">Help</a></li>
```

when you render your child template the 'fragments/own_menu.html' will be searched in the current app first.